# Dealing with missing month values in dataset and plotting a time series

Tags: r

So i currently have a dataset in R:

```
Date            Mean_Value

2003-10-01      7.94
2004-02-01      3.17
2004-03-01      4.62
2004-04-01      5.38
2004-05-01      4.17
2004-06-01      6.40
2004-07-01      4.12
2004-08-01      3.09
2005-01-01      5.32
.
.
```

and I'm planning to **plot a time series** for the above dataset, but one thing I'm concerned with is that is it the right thing to do, to just plot the time series even though there are **some months of the year** in the dataset above **missing?** for example, in the year **2003**, the missing months are **"November" and "December"** while in the year **2004**, the months missing are **"September,October,November and December"**.

The year list goes on until 2012, and there are indeed **some years with all months present**. Although some years are missing certain months like the example above, would i still be able to plot the time series, ignoring the fact that there **exist missing months** in some years?

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `xts` and then do the `plot`

```
library(xts)
xt1 <- xts(df1$Mean_Value, order.by = as.Date(df1$Date))
plot(xt1)
```

---

Or use `complete` to create the missing 'Date' and then with `ggplot` plot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
   complete(Date = seq(first(Date), last(Date), by = "1 month"), 
         fill = list(Mean_Value = 0)) %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(x = Date, y = Mean_Value)) + 
           geom_line()
```

Comment: what is the difference between xts and the standard ts plot?

Comment: @Maxxx  It would be more flexible to format the x axis

Comment: so plotting a normal time series with missing month is not wrong, but using xts gives it more flexibility and improve the overall plot?

Comment: @Maxxx  It depends on what values you want the missing months to fill.  In the second option, I filled it with 0s and plot with `ggplot`.  Can you check it